# information hidding in Javascript will sacrifice performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My main question is the following:

> is [information hidding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) going to hurt perfomance(Both CPU/Memory) when you have a
> frequently-accessed function (returning an object) that you want
> people to interact with?

Or is this considered micro-optimization especially when using a platform like for example **node.js(long running process)**. Should I consider performance over information hidding or not?

---

By reading  [Douglas Crockford's article about information hidding](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) I know I can add private members and privileged methods. But according to this quote from Douglas Crockford the prototype mechanism helps you conserve memory:

> When a member is sought and it isn't found in the object itself, then
> it is taken from the object's constructor's prototype member. The
> prototype mechanism is used for inheritance. It also conserves memory.

When only memory is saved then I guess this might not be such a big deal because memory is getting cheaper by the second. But according to [this article from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) it is also faster(CPU) to add a lot of properties the prototype chain.

> Thus, if you have a frequently-accessed function (returning an object)
> that you want people to interact with, then it's to your advantage to
> have the object properties be in the prototype chain and instantiate
> it.
>
> Instantiating a function with a bunch of prototype properties is very,
> very, fast. It completely blows the Module pattern, and similar, out
> of the water. Thus, if you have a frequently-accessed function
> (returning an object) that you want people to interact with, then it's
> to your advantage to have the object properties be in the prototype
> chain and instantiate it.
>
> ```
> // Very fast
> function User(){}
> User.prototype = { /* Lots of properties ... */ };
> // Very slow
> function User(){
>   return { /* Lots of properties */ };
> }
> ```

This  also might not be such a big problem because CPU's are getting much faster(Moore's Law). Furthermore because the Javascript engines made incredible progress performance-wise I am wondering if I should even consider this or just use information hidding.

---

I also have this sub-question I guess:

> How would I effectively measure both memory and CPU using a platform like for
> example node.js?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth  and Make It Work Make It Right Make It Fast: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast . When it's working, and you've profiled, and it's slow, only then optimize it. Even if it's slow, it'll probably be fast enough in most circumstances...

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. You're asking which style of object creation has the best memory and time performance, but it's totally in the abstract. It depends on a lot of issues, not the least of which is how many objects are to be created. If you don't have a concrete case, then don't worry about performance at this stage. Go for what will make it easiest for you to debug. As A. Nonymous said, _"I'd rather optimize a debugged program than debug an optimized program."_

Comment: I know about Donald Knuth. So I guess I should consider information hidding first.

Comment: How do you people do(prefer) it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sure sounds to me like you're trying to over optimize something that rarely needs optimizing.  Wirte your cost first to be reliable, second to be maintainable by you or others and then optimize only the things that really need optimizing after you get proof that it needs optimizing.

First off, making things truly private adds complication.  You should likely use a member variable unless you really, really need the privacy.

Second off, closures to implement privacy do come at some sort of memory consumption cost.  The amount of memory is small per use so if you really need the privacy (the first point), then unless you have a LOT of these closures, you will probably not even notice the additional consumption.

Third, if you have a lot of these objects (e.g. thousands) and you suspect the memory consumption might actually be an important issue, then you probably should do a quick memory test in a couple of popular browsers (one version with the private closure and one with the simpler public member variable) to see how much of a difference there is.  The difference is implementation specific so could vary significantly from one browser to the next.

Based on the findings of these measurments, you could decide which way to go.

If you don't have thousands of these objects, then write your code the simplest way possible that achieves your objectives and spend your time working on things that show you they really matter once you're running your app.

Comment: But I wonder if you know if it is it only increased memory usage or also increased CPU usage(in what kind of order o(N))? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: P.S: I guess I should mention I would also like to use in a long running process using like for example node.js.

Comment: @Alfred - there may be a few more CPU cycles initializing an object one way or the other.  You'd have to test to be sure, but I can't imagine that part would be significant.  It doesn't matter that it's a long running process.  What matters is how many of these objects you would have and whether the additional memory they would consume is significant to the environment that you're expecting to run them in.  You haven't given us any of the necessary data for us to assess that question.

Comment: Okay I guess this question of mine is not so good so I should close it.

Comment: Just a note: the Resig article the OP cited was written in December 2007. At that time all the JavaScript implementations in common use were seriously slow, and so a certain degree of micro-optimization was often necessary. Things have improved tremendously in the four-and-a-half years since.

Comment: @ebohlman that was my question :P. Thanks?